# Proper data model for lists of data in Big Table DB

Tags: database-design, bigtable

This feels like a dumb question, but what is the proper way to associate a key with a list of values in Big Table?  If it's a column for each item, what is the column name?  item-1, item-2, etc where item is a prefix that identifies the list.  If that's the case, I would have to somehow query the length of the list each time - possibly via an item-size column.

Alternatively, I could just store the list as a JSON array, but that seems bad.  Wondering what the experts out there think?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to model an entity that owns lists of values. Instead of making each item in the list a separate row, you can make another table

Entity: **ID**(Primary Key), other data 
ListItem: **Entity_ID**(Foreign Key to **Entity.ID**), value

This way your list can have as many values as necessary